# Calculate someone's pay, including overtime

Tags: java, beginner

In this problem, you need to calculate someone's pay by multiplying their salary (double)by the hours (int) worked. If they worked for more than 8 hours, you pay them 1.5 times their salary for however many hours more they worked.
Here is my solution.

```
public static double pay(double a, int b) {
if (b > 8) {
    return (a * 8) + ((b - 8)*(a * 1.5));
}
else {
    return (a * b);
}}
```

Wondering if there is any way to do it without if else statements since the course hasn't taught those yet.

Comment: Shouldn't hours be a double as well?  People don't always work an integer values of hours, especially when there's overtime involved.

Comment: In this case, the problem specifically asked that hours be an int.

Comment: A course is having you do programming without teaching you if else statements first? I cannot think of a more elementary logical construct.

Comment: But this isn't some massive project. Just a simple lab that tests we know the Math class. I didn't really think about using the math class since overtime was conditional, so I did it this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the answer given by rolfl, you can also remove the `if-else` and do it like this:

```
public static double pay(double a, int b) {
    int regularHours = Math.min(8, b);
    int extraHours = b - regularHours;
    return (a * regularHours) + (extraHours * a * 1.5);
}
```

Comment: This is most likely how they wanted to do it. I was never thinking about max at the time.

Comment: Probably. Just keep in mind that if you had to solve the problem without using any 3rd party methods (`max` is a method of `Math` which is included in the `java.lang` package and is written by someone else) but just the language, the method written by @rolfl is the way to go.

Comment: Note that this gives the wrong answers..... http://ideone.com/fvAhZY - also, `Math.max(...)` is in fact, a conditional - [in fact it is a few of them](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Math.java#Math.max%28double%2Cdouble%29)

Comment: @rolfl, you're right (guess it happens when the code is not tested). Now the bug [is fixed](https://ideone.com/nf0bGS). Regarding `Math.max` (and also `Math.min` in this case) I'm well aware of the fact that they use conditionals internally, but in this context (it was the answer in a course where the students hadn't yet learned about the `if-else` construct) it was the most probable solution.

Comment: @rolfl The Math class is a pretty big part of the course (atm), so the expectation was definitely going to be that we find a solution by using it.

Comment: The `Math.max(...)` is unnecessary. A simple `b - regularHours` would be better. .... but, then you sort of end up with my solution too ;-)

Comment: You're right about the `Math.max(...)` part. Changed it. Thanks for the great feedback :)

Answer (score 11):

You should use better variable names, for a start.... consider:

```
public static double pay(double hourlyWage, int hours) {
    ...
}
```

Then, your code is not that bad (with some indentation fixes too):

```
public static double pay(double hourlyWage, int hours) {
    if (hours > 8) {
        return (hourlyWage * 8) + ((hours - 8)*(hourlyWage * 1.5));
    }
    else {
        return (hourlyWage * hours);
    }
}
```

There is no good way to handle the overtime rate other than with a conditional somewhere. Ternary conditions may help a bit.....

```
public static double pay(double hourlyWage, int hours) {
    int regular = hours > 8 ? 8 : hours;
    int overtime = hours - regular;
    return hourlyWage * (regular + (1.5 * overtime));
}
```

Comment: Alright. I wonder how they were expecting us to do the problem. This is a fine solution anyway. Thanks

Comment: I'm over thinking the problem but I would extract 8 as a magic numbers if it was in a real application. The maximum workable hours in the real world can change easily for a lot of reasons. Your solution is really elegant and I don't think it could be more readable than what it's currently is.

Comment: @Marc-Andre, yeah, and I'd say `1.5` also (for the same reasons)